# Lock buttons for further release in iOS

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

I've re-read apple's guides and there are no answer for me: my app is divided on levels -- first, second etc. User can't buy new level unless previous has not completed. I want to use built-it IAP and my problem - i've designed app for more than 10 levels, but really completed only a few -- should I remove all other levels buttons from main screen or I can left it in place with "disable" mode? I'm interesting in app review and possibility rejecting of app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that your app will be rejected if there are some buttons can not be clicked. Instead of leaving some buttons disabled, you'd better add some message to them, such as a lovely "Coming soon" screen will be a good idea and safe (See how the level-based game doing, Angry Bird or Cut the Rope).

Comment: ok, thanx, it seems to be a good idea with "coming soon" pix